# Android: datepickerdialog header doesn't look like it should

Tags: java, android, widget, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I'm creating a datepickerdialog like this:

```
Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

myDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
// do something
}
}
, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

myDatePicker.show();
```

Unfortunately what I'm getting back is something that looks like this:

[image: what I'm getting]

And what I actually want to get is something that looks like this:

[image: what I want to get]

I'm talking about the header. I want the day, and under that the month, day of the month, year.. This seems to be fairly standard and default because I've seen loads of example screenshots that look like that floating around, but obviously I'm doing something wrong because it doesn't look like that for me.

Edit: a potential workaround for this is to use the third party library:

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

but this isn't ideal. I'm still hoping for a solution that doesn't require third party libraries.

Comment: in which device are you running this?

Comment: I mean the screen size of the device

Comment: it's a nexus 5 phone

Comment: which theme are you using as base theme for your app?

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

Comment: use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`  and verify the same. I think this might be either because of small screen size or the base theme of your app.

Comment: @Jon A little bit smaller image would suffice, it can be done by changing `tTSZJ.png` to `tTSZJm.png`

Comment: @SMR - I tried using the Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar but it still looks about the same. The header is a lighter gray color now.